# Load dll function from other directory

Tags: c++, dll

in my new project, I got a problem about loading dll.
My file structure is like below:

1. D:\dll_directory\calculate.dll
2. D:\myproject\myproject.vcxproj
3. D:\running_place\myproject.exe

There're my code,

```
HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("D:\\dll_directory\\calculate.dll");
if(!h)
    return GetLastError();

pfnInit     = (PInit)GetProcAddress(h, "initialize");
if(!pfnInit())
{
    // Fail
}
```

In my code of calculate.dll, I need to get the working directory so I use

```
int initialize() {
    ...
    GetModuleFileName(...,myPath,...);
    currentPath = ...; // get directory from path
    filePath = currentPath + ...
    if(!DoesExist(filePath))
        return 0;
    ...
}
```

The problem is there. Because I loadlibrary dll from "D:\dll_directory\" in other directory, currentPath value is wrong.

In debugging, currentPath is "D:\myproject\debug..." and in executing, it's "D:\running_place\".

Only if place myproject.exe into the same place with calculate.dll, **it shows correctly, currentPath = "D:\dll_directory\"**.

But I don't want to place dll manually because of many files and many places.
Additionally, I can not change code in dlls, it's stable.

Are there any ways to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

**Updated**: I modify my question to more clearer. Sr about this. It's my first time on stackoverflow.

In function Init of DLL, it need to run other files that are placed in the same place with it. The expected of currentPath is directory of DLL.

EXE in dir1 loads DLL in dir2, EXE calls function Init of DLL -> currentPath=dir1 (wrong).

Try to change DLL code with GetCurrentDirectory -> currentPath=dir1; still wrong.

Put EXE and DLL in dir2, EXE calls function Init of DLL -> currentPath=dir2 (expected).

Comment: You vaguely describe something that does not help you in what you want to achieve, but it's still unclear what you want to achieve. Why do you need this "current path" and why are the results you get wrong?

Comment: Hi Eckhardt, I updated the question.

Comment: I think the answers below already give you the pieces to the whole picture,  still missing is this "current path". There is something called "working directory" or "current working directory", which is a property of a running process that most operating systems support. It is used to resolve relative (as opposed to absolute) paths like "../file.text". This path can change during the runtime of the process, e.g. the `cd` or `pushd` commands in the commandline shell do. However, this is not what you need, you only need to use `GetModuleFileName()` with the right module, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed using the wrong function t get the current directory. `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the current directory (i.e. where `.\thisFile.txt` would be sought).

`GetModuleFileName` returns the name where the module came from. That's in general not the current working directory. That working directory can be pretty much anything, really. The variation you see between debug and release is just a small sample of the possible variation. Expect anything.

It also appears that you're looking for another file, other than the 3 mentioned in the question. It's unclear where that other file is located, so it's possible that this answer is incomplete. Is there a reason to expect that other file in the current working directory?

Comment: thank Salters, uhm let say in short, I want to my exe that is placed in folder A calls dll that is placed in folder B, but currentPath is set wrong. I'll try to debug with GetCurrentDirectory and GetModuleFileName.

Comment: Still a bit unclear. As the debugging tips suggest, reduce the problem to the simplest size. Try to make an EXE and a DLL which literally does nothing else but load, with the EXE in dir1 and the DLL in dir2. I don't even see why you need `currentPath` whatever that is.

Comment: In function Init DLL, it need to run other files that are placed in the same place with it. That why `currentPath` is there.
EXE in dir1 loads DLL in dir2, EXE calls function Init of DLL -> `currentPath=dir1`.
EXE and DLL in dir2, EXE calls function Init of DLL -> `currentPath=dir2` (expected).
Try to change DLL code with `GetCurrentDirectory` -> `currentPath=dir1`; still wrong.

Comment: @oni.HD: Right. You really should have put that in the question. As for the problem at hand, your use of "current path" is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `GetModuleFileName` (which you left out) determines which path to get. From the observed behavior, we can now deduce that you passed `NULL` or `0`, which means you get the filename of the EXE module.
You should have passed `HMODULE h` from your first snippet, the DLL module.

(This value is also available inside your `DllMain`, 1st argument. Save that 1st argument to a global variable in your DLL, so you can pass it to `GetModuleFileName`)

Comment: I really don't understand this: "you should have passed HMODULE h from your first snippet, the DLL module. (This value is also available inside your DllMain, 1st argument)"

That HMODULE I get in EXE, how to pass it to DLL, I don't want to change the function parameter of DLL. Could you explain more details?

In addition, I find out a way, in the below answer.

Comment: @oni.HD: I had also indicated the second way of getting the `HMODULE` in your DLL, I've made it more explicit that you can simply save this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I find out these code that return the DLL current path.

```
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
WCHAR   DllPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, DllPath, _countof(DllPath));
```

Actually, I don't know what _ImageBase is and its cons/pros, am still investigating.

If ok, maybe I use it in DLL code.

Comment: `__ImageBase`  is a pseudo-symbol used by the Microsoft linker, which is the same as the first argument from ` DllMain` except for the type. That's why you need the cast. (`HINSTANCE` is a synonym for `HMODULE` nowadays, they were different in 16 bits Windows)